# Запятая в нижеприведенном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, запятые, и

«От вас ждут сочувствия и ничего другого».

Верно ли без запятой перед «и ничего другого»? От вас ждут чего? Сочувствия. И от вас ждут чего? Ничего другого. Так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще можно сослаться на синтаксическую целостность словосочетания "Сочувствия и ничего другого". Как в предложениях:

```
Сочувствие и ничего другого исходило от них.
Бессмысленность и ничего более звучала в его словах.
Он смотрел на это как на скуку и ничего более.
Я дам тебе доллар и ни цента больше.
Сегодня и никогда более вы увидите супершоу.
Он работал врачом и никем более.
```

Comment: Так люди не говорят, только четвёртый пример правильный в плане стилистики. Берите примеры из Нацкорпуса, выдумать можно что угодно. Где прописана допустимость такой синтаксической целостности?

Comment: Опять рассматриваете только грамматику?

Answer (score 4):

***От вас ждут сочувствия, и ничего другого.***

Я тоже, как Артём и oleedd, думаю, что что-то здесь не так, и тоже хотел добавить ***только***. Если и оформлять предложение как есть, то запятая необходима. Мы не можем сказать, что ***сочувствие*** и ***ничего другого*** объединены одним сказуемым. Первого ***ждут***, а второго ***не ждут***. (Вопрос о том, можно ли считать пропущенный глагол с отрицанием однородным такому же глаголу без отрицания, я пока не прорабатывал. Если кто намекнёт или даст ссылку – спасибо.)

В варианте с запятой (если он "нормален") мы сталкиваемся с присоединительным союзом ***и***. (см. [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100))

***От вас ничего не ждут, кроме сочувствия.***

Comment: *Вопрос о том...* — см. пятый комментарий под ответом user190920.

Answer (score 1):

*И ничего другого* выступает здесь в роли частицы (ср. *и ничего более*); обособление факультативно. Стилистика предложения выглядит непривычно, но не настолько же, чтобы считаться ошибочной. Примеры правильного и красивого литературного языка лучше искать у хороших филологов, хороших писателей, да и просто в книгах добротных издательств. Ниже несколько примеров — с обособлением и без.

> Но журнал есть журнал, и отдел поэзии требует стихов и ничего другого.
> (Маргарита Алигер, Советский писатель, 1980)
>
> У меня ничего другого нет. Только работа, и ничего другого. (С.П.
> Бабаевский, Собрание сочинений, Художественная литература, 1980)
>
> Лучше дайте поскорее винтовку и ничего другого. (Иностранная
> литература, 1981)

Comment: И если вы находите десятки добротных примеров, противоречащих вашему вкусу, это повод задуматься о своём вкусе, а не о том, что все грамотные и образованные люди опять ошиблись.

Comment: Это не частица, так как слово ‟ничего” может изменяться по роду: ничего более и никого более, ничего другого и никого другого.

Comment: Я не знаю, что Вы называете **родом**. Впрочем, неважно. *Ничего более* в обсуждаемом значении так не изменяется.

Comment: Нет, употребляться,  вот предложение: ‟Приведите мне только его и никого другого”. Что касается рода: ‟ничего” — средний род, ‟никого” — мужской род. Даже если это не одно слово (а это вопрос просто условностей), то в любом случает подобные сочетания собираются по правилам грамматики, а не являются устоявшимися сочетаниями — частицами. Вот еще, кстати, вариант: ‟Мне нужна только она и никто другой”. В обоих примерах можно убрать ‟только”, если эта частица смущает.

Comment: Да и по падежам изменяется: ‟и никто другой”, ‟и никого другого”. Вот пример: ‟Я дам эти деньги ему и никому другому”. Еще: ‟Я восхищаюсь им и никем другим”. Вот пример с ‟ничего” с другим падежом: ‟Я воспользуюсь этим и ничем другим”.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/255/%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE), как отличить частицу от членов предложения. Погуглите по учебникам. Если не сможете разобраться, задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Это я не могу разобраться?! Прекрасно! Еще раз. Вот два предложения: ‟Лучше дайте поскорее винтовку и ничего другого”(пример из вашего ответа) и ‟Я воспользуюсь винтовкой и ничем другим”(я изменил его так, чтобы изменился падеж). У частицы изменяется падеж?! Или это не похожее использование этого сочетание и это другое?

Comment: В первом предложении это частица (Вы просто не понимаете смысл этого предложения), а во втором это члены предложения. К сожалению, не могу уделить Вам больше времени по этому вопросу.

Comment: Да, вы правы, я не понимаю простое предложение, потому что у меня инсульт и я подзабыл часть родного языка.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, предложение составлено не очень удачно. Я бы переформулировал так:

***От вас ждут только сочувствия — ничего другого.***

Oleedd навёл меня ещё и на другой возможный вариант с И:

***От вас ждут сочувствия — и только.***

Comment: А я это как раз имел в виду. ;) Запятая вроде не нужна несмотря ни на какие присоединения.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_813

Comment: Хах, убедил! Спасибо! Ты чего пропал, кстати, хитрец?

Comment: Мало кому нужны эти ответы, мало кто ценит труд и время здесь. А на это порой дни уходят (с утра до вечера доказывал). Почти пустая трата времени. А сам отвечаешь раз в месяц, и то кратко. Это кто ещё хитрец.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь неудачно использование союза И. Это неудачно для предложений с тематикой надобности (когда надо, ждут чего-то). Вот похожие предложения, которые не являются верными в плане стилистики:
*От него ждут оплаты и ничего другого.

Ему нужно сделать д/з и ничего другого.

Ему надо сходить на рынок и больше никуда.*
Даже с присоединением (с запятой) такое не удачно.

Без союза И уже становится нормально. "И ничего другого" вполне заменяется сочетанием "и всё" или словом "только" ("ждут только").

Если отбросить проблемы со стилистикой, то нужна ли запятая? Если есть пауза, то да.

Update:
Сочетание "и ничего больше" удачно, когда что-то где-то находится (*там росли сосны и ничего больше; на столе книга и ничего больше*), появляется (*это вызвало только улыбку и ничего больше*), даётся (*получишь только 100 рублей и ничего больше*) — но не когда кому-то следует что-то сделать (такая же тематика в обсуждаемом примере):
*Ему нужно купить хлеб и ничего больше.*
С "только" звучит гораздо лучше, например:
*Это вызвало (только) улыбку и ничего больше.*
Это сочетание классифицируется как частица с факультативным обособлением:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_224
Оно не взаимозаменяемо на "и ничего другого" во многих примерах, хоть и по смыслу очень похоже. В Нацкорпусе "и ничего другого" редко стоит в конце предложения, а если и стоит, то почти всегда с запятой. Оно не настолько самостоятельно и устойчиво и до частицы не дотягивает.

Update 2:
Целесообразность зависит от глагола. Глагол "ждать" не подходит для "и ничего другого/больше".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой "Неудачное использование" здесь звучит не очень, разговорно, мне такое не подходит.

Comment: Ну странно, что не подходит! Нормально звучит. Но я понял этот вариант теперь, так тоже можно.

Comment: Хм, а разница вот в чём: *неудачное использование* vs *использование союза И неудачно*. Краткая форма более самостоятельна, характерна для научного стиля.

Comment: Да я понял это.

Comment: С ‟ и ничего другого ” вообще нет таких примеров в Нац. корпусе. Оно намного реже используется, чем ‟ ничего больше ”, и ситуация довольно редкая. Речь не идет о взаимозаменяемости этих сочетаний, а о том, как разрешаются такие ситуации, где одно однородное дополнение требует двойного отрицания, а другое не требует.  Это может быть абсолютно любое подобное сочетание.  Вопрос идет о конкретной синтаксической ситуации. Мне просто нечего добавить. Это вопрос вкуса, и люди конструируют предложения таким образом.

Comment: Но "и ничего больше" частица, как "и всё", "и только". А "и ничего другого" в конце не используется и до частицы не доросло.

Comment: Это частица только потому, что какой-то грамотей так решил. Если ‟и ничего больше” частица, то и ‟ничего другого” тоже частица.

Comment: Такие частицы используются в конце, а ‟и ничего другого” не используется. Дело в этом.

Comment: В данном случае ‟ничего другого” не частица только потому, что это сочетание намного реже употребляется и этот же грамотей просто не рассмотрел это сочетание. Если бы это сочетание попалось этому грамотею, то оно также улетело бы в частицы. В первом предложении ( Корнея Чуковского ) ‟ничего больше” не находится в конце.

Comment: К тому же, это очень странно, что оно занесено в частицы, так как может быть дополнением. Я не жду ничего больше.

Comment: Ну вы юморист. Приколы про грамотея, который от фонаря реформирует язык, зачётны. На самом деле это решает коллектив лингвистов, уж точно не один. А там указано, что может быть в конце части сложного предложения (так у Чуковского). Если дополнение, то нарушение грамматики, а занесение в частицы нивелирует ошибку.

Comment: Конечно же по поводу тонких вопросов классификации слов по частям речи нет консенсуса. Лингвополенья постоянно выпускают книги со своим видением классификации подобных тонких случаев. На Граммоте опубликовано мнение случайного лингвополена.

Comment: На Грамоте опубликовано мнение академии наук.

Comment: @oleedd  Это не частица, так как слово ‟ничего” может изменяться по роду: ничего более и никого более, ничего другого и никого другого. Чьё бы мнение не было опубликовано на Грамоте — оно ошибочно.

Comment: @oleedd По падежам также изменяется. Вот пример с ‟ничего” с другим падежом: ‟Я воспользуюсь этим и ничем другим”.

Comment: @oleedd Если на Грамоте мнение РАН, то это грубейшая ошибка со стороны РАН.

Comment: Это словосочетание, выполняющее функцию частицы. А ваш критерий можно отнести к слову-частице. Это лишь условная частица, такие критерии к ней не применимы.

Answer (score 0):

Звучит отлично. Все так. Запятая не нужна ввиду общего подлежащего **они**. Полное предложение такое:

```
Они от вас ждут сочувствия и не ждут (от них) ничего другого.
```

Comment: Можно ещё слова попропускать, будет "ещё отличнее": *Ждут сочувствия и ничего.* Всем же понятно, что пропущено. Вообще-то частица НЕ не пропускается.

Comment: Если всем понятно, то можно, если нет, то нет.

Comment: Не только, ещё и звучать должно нормально.

Comment: Звучит отлично, см мой ответ.

Comment: Не звучит такое. Например: *Он купил хлеб и не купил масло.* Надо так: *Он купил хлеб, а масло — нет.* Должно быть хоть какое-то противопоставление.

Comment: Пример не в тему. Из первоначального примера однозначно выводится частица не. Из вашего примера - нет. Но рассуждать о звучании, все равно что спорить о вкусах. Оно либо есть, либо нет

Comment: А это о вашем варианте. Вы ж сказали "см мой ответ".

Comment: Такой пример: *Он ждёт автобуса и не ждёт трамвая. — Он ждёт автобуса, и ничего другого.*

Comment: Частицу НЕ нельзя пропускать. Это даже против грамматики — необходимо двойное отрицание.

Comment: ‟Он купил хлеб и не купил масло” — отличное предложение, в нем нет ничего неправильного. То же самое с: ‟ Он ждет автобуса и не ждёт трамвая ”.

Comment: @JimKorbett Стилистику учитывайте, а не только грамматику. Необходимо противопоставление, чтобы было грамотно: *Он купил хлеб, **но** не купил масло. Он ждет автобуса, **а** не трамвая.*

Comment: Между ‟ купил хлеб ” и ‟ не купил масло ” не обязательно есть противительные отношения. Это может быть перечисление того, что он купил и не купил.

Comment: @JimKorbett Такое не особо удачно в плане стилистики.

Comment: Это не вопрос стилистики, просто с ‟ но ” появляются противительные отношения и другой смысл предложения, а с ‟ и ” просто перечисление того, что сделал этот человек.

Comment: Вот и просто перечисление неудачно, в таких случаях оно не используется. Более яркий пример: *Он съел печенье и не съел суп.* Это как ставить запятую при следствии, пояснении.

Comment: В этом предложении то же самое: все зависит от того, что вы хотите сконструировать. Если это просто беспристрастное наблюдение за кем-то с описывание всех действий, которые совершает субъект, то вариант с ‟ и ” не является какой-либо ошибкой.

Comment: Разве что беспристрастное наблюдение [за испытуемым].

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос привел к длинной дискуссии, из которой трудновато вычленить рациональное зерно. А оно, не сомневаюсь, в том, что в этом предложении союз "и" употребляется в присоединительном значении "и притом", поэтому запятая, несомненно, нужна

Answer (score 0):

Здесь первое дополнение обычное, а второе требует двойного отрицания. Это очень редкая ситуация, и нормировать её никто не будет.  Хотя такое написание формально и противоречит грамматике ( а не стилистике ), но писать так или нет все же дело вкуса. В Нац. корпусе такие предложения конструируют:

> Если бы англичане создали только читальный зал и ничего больше ― они и тогда заслужили бы имя великой нации. [К. И. Чуковский. Корреспонденции из Лондона (1903-1904)]

> «Сегодня продаётся только „красота и чистота” и ничего больше. [Екатерина Ткачёва. Война и мир в Ясной поляне Калининграда (2017.08.19)]

> Все будет только оптический обман и ничего больше… [Л. Я. Гинзбург. Записные книжки. Воспоминания. Эссе (1920-1943)]

> Может быть, действительно он ждал только дождей и ничего больше. [Василий Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)]

> «Сима, ты получишь деревянную крышку на гроб и ничего больше!» [В. А. Ярмолинец. Лев в Москве // «Волга», 2015] [омонимия не снята]

> Стол застелен чистой бумагой, на ней чернильный прибор и ничего больше. [А. А. Бек. Талант (Жизнь Бережкова)

> Когда мы миновали эту пустыню, то попали в другую, где росли только телеграфные столбы и ничего больше. [Евгений Петров, Илья Ильф. Одноэтажная Америка (1936)]

> Это были действительно шпильки и ничего больше. [П. С. Романов. Без черемухи (1927)]
> Весь мост на виду мне, а им только видны стрижиные гнезда и ничего больше. [В. А. Гиляровский. Ваня Кузнец (1912)]

> Вчерашнюю ночь луна вызвала у Наташи только художественный восторг и ничего больше. [А. А. Луговой. Девичье поле // «Нива», № 14-23, 1909]

Comment: Ага, значит "ждут ничего другого", оказывается, правильно.

Comment: Это неполное предложение от: ‟ Они не ждут  сочувствия и ничего другого кроме сочувствия”.

Comment: ‟ ничего другого ” = ‟ ничего другого кроме сочувствия ”.

Comment: Так и есть. Под ‟ничего другого” подразумевается ‟ничего другого кроме сочувствия”, просто это неполное предложение.

Comment: В оригинале нет частицы НЕ, а у вас есть.

Comment: Это ничего не меняет, а просто описка. Я уже не могу отменить обратно.

Comment: Это неполное предложение от: ‟ Они ждут сочувствия и ничего другого кроме сочувствия”.

Comment: *Ждут ничего другого, кроме сочувствия* — некорректно.

Comment: Необходимо двойное отрицание. Нельзя ждать ничего, что бы вы ни добавили после.

Comment: Ответ на комментарий в дополненном ответе.

Comment: С "и ничего больше" немного другая история. Оно звучит лучше и более самостоятельно.

Comment: Вопрос именно о ситуации, где одно дополнение требует двойного отрицания, а другое не требует.  О каких-то тонких эманациях, где что-то там звучит по-другому, я спорить не буду. Там, кстати, в конце предложение от Корнея Чуковского, который является крайне авторитетным автором.

Comment: Дело в том, что в этих примерах оно звучит — там есть "только", — а в примере из вопроса нет.

Comment: Не во всех есть ‟ только ”. Не вижу, что оно меняет. Есть еще тьма примеров без ‟ только ”.

Comment: Все там прекрасно звучит, в примере из вопроса.

Comment: Немудрено, раз у вас звучит "ждут ничего другого, кроме сочувствия".

Comment: Нет, я согласен, что тут требуется двойное отрицание и это грамматическая ошибка.

Comment: Я только что даже коварно удалил этот комментарий.

Comment: Ага, кажись, начинаю понимать, в чём дело. Такое используется, когда что-то где-то находится, появляется (не только), но не когда кому-то нужно что-то сделать. Например: *Ему нужно помыть посуду и больше ничего.*

Comment: Ответ обновлен. Так что стоит искать именно "и ничего другого".